# python, django: copy image

Tags: python, django, image, copy

I created this function, to copy an image from a django-model to another django-model. The image has to be saved redundantly:

```
def __copy_file__(from_object,to_object,field):
    attr = field.attname
    try:
        newpath = getattr(from_object,attr).path
        dot_at = newpath.rfind(".")
        while os.path.exists(newpath):
            newpath = newpath[:dot_at] + "_" + newpath[dot_at:]
        shutil.copyfile(getattr(from_object,attr).path, newpath)
        getattr(to_object,attr).save(newpath, File(open(getattr(from_object,attr).path)))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

But this function creates somehow invalid files.. I can remember it worked one day, but i tested it today and it isn't working anymore..

Edit: Now i know that the function produces two images. One that works and one that doesn't. The line `shutil.copyfile (etc)` produces the working one and in the assignment `getattr(to_object,attr).save (etc)` the image gets saved again. So this is the problem. It should just be assigned, not copied again..

Can anybody help me? :)

Comment: "it isn't working anymore".  I wonder what this means.  Anyone have a guess?

Comment: The function works not anymore. Now it creates invalid files. I'm pretty sure it was working when i wrote that function (probably one month ago)

Answer (score 3):

the way I do it, assuming `from_model` and `to_model` are to models instances with an image ImageField:

```
def copy_image(from_model, to_model):
    to_model.image.save(from_model.image.url.split('/')[-1],from_model.image.file,save=True)
```